# why emqx memory increase until system occurs a oom-killer?

Tags: memory-leaks, erlang, emqx

After a week,the memories used by the emqx increases,about two weeks more until a oom-killer occurs by the system.The processes are no more than max count of processes.
I try the follow commands ,and don't know the reason. Can anyone please help me?

version: emqx 4.2.14,ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS,

details as follows:

emqx remote_console information on the remote server.

```
========================================================================================
 'emqx@127.0.0.1'                                                          01:01:02
 Load:  cpu         1               Memory:  total     5515460    binary    2269778
        procs     381                        processes 3072341    code        29676
        runq        0                        atom         1410    ets          7194

Pid            Name or Initial Func    Time    Reds  Memory    MsgQ Current Function
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<8867.29600.2> emqx_connection:init     '-'      42******** 2246890 gen:do_call/4
<8867.19863.2> emqx_connection:init     '-'      42******** 2320382 gen:do_call/4
<8867.28846.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     753 4723508       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28855.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     753 4722476       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28890.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     753 4721388       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28845.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     753 4720788       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28851.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     712 2919140       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28840.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     753 1948636       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28959.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     891 1804500       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.29000.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'  218185 1804456       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28946.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'     753 1804444       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.28862.11>emqx_connection:init     '-'    2343 1803900       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.1405.0>  ranch_sup                '-'       1  602176       0 gen_server:loop/7
<8867.28966.11>etop_txt:init/1          '-'   19209  426700       0 etop:update/1
<8867.1288.0>  application_controll     '-'       1  319556       0 gen_server:loop/7
<8867.28942.11>erlang:apply/2           '-'       1  264164       0 shell:get_command1/5
<8867.1621.0>  ranch_conns_sup:init     '-'      42  236152       0 ranch_conns_sup:loop
<8867.1599.0>  ranch_conns_sup:init     '-'       2  230544       0 ranch_conns_sup:loop
<8867.1954.0>  emqx_connection:init     '-'    3434  143280       0 emqx_connection:recv
<8867.1807.0>  emqx_connection:init     '-'    3574  143224       0 emqx_connection:recv
========================================================================================
```

one process information:

```
(emqx@127.0.0.1)3> process_info(pid(0,29600,2), current_stacktrace).
{current_stacktrace,[{gen,do_call,4,
                          [{file,"gen.erl"},{line,167}]},
                     {gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,219}]},
                     {emqx_cm,takeover_session,2,
                              [{file,"emqx_cm.erl"},{line,267}]},
                     {emqx_cm,'-open_session/3-fun-1-',5,
                              [{file,"emqx_cm.erl"},{line,222}]},
                     {emqx_cm_locker,trans,3,
                                     [{file,"emqx_cm_locker.erl"},{line,46}]},
                     {emqx_channel,process_connect,2,
                                   [{file,"emqx_channel.erl"},{line,434}]},
                     {emqx_connection,with_channel,3,
                                      [{file,"emqx_connection.erl"},{line,553}]},
                     {emqx_connection,process_msg,3,
                                      [{file,"emqx_connection.erl"},{line,293}]}]}
```

another process

```
rp(erlang:process_info(pid(0,19863,2), backtrace)).
{backtrace,<<"Program counter: 0x00007fe26a53d860 (gen:do_call/4 + 3168)\n
CP: 0x0000000000000000 (invalid)\n\n
0x00007fde7c33fa28 Return addr 0x00007fe26a551908 (gen_server:call/3 + 128)\n
y(0)     infinity\n
y(1)     []\n
y(2)     #Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.17060>\n
y(3)     <0.19863.2>\n\n
0x00007fde7c33fa50 Return addr 0x00007fe2681a03d0 (emqx_cm:takeover_session/2 + 312)\n
y(0)     infinity\n
y(1)     {takeover,begin}\n
y(2)     <0.19863.2>\n
y(3)     Catch 0x00007fe26a551908 (gen_server:call/3 + 128)\n\n
0x00007fde7c33fa78 Return addr 0x00007fe2681a28192 (emqx_cm:'-open_session/3-fun-1-'/5 + 96)\n
y(0)     emqx_connection\n
y(1)     <0.19863.2>\n\n
0x00007fde7c33fa90 Return addr 0x00007fe26819a978 (emqx_cm_locker:trans/3 + 360)\n
y(0)     []\n
y(1)     []\n
y(2)     <0.19863.2>\n
y(3)     <<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>\n
y(4)     #{clean_start=>false,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,conn_mod=>emqx_connection,conn_props=>#{},connected_at=>1701153199092,disconnected_at=>1701153199091,expiry_interval=>71680,keepalive=>60,peercert=>nossl,peername=>{{192,168,30,43},57440},proto_name=><<\"MQTT\">>,proto_ver=>4,receive_maximum=>32,sockname=>{{192,168,30,16},1883},socktype=>tcp,username=><<\"admin\">>}\n
y(5)     #{anonymous=>true,auth_result=>success,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,is_bridge=>false,is_superuser=>false,mountpoint=>undefined,peerhost=>{192,168,30,43},protocol=>mqtt,sockport=>1883,username=><<\"admin\">>,zone=>external}\n\n
0x00007fde7c33fac8 Return addr 0x00007fe26818192b8 (emqx_channel:process_connect/2 + 168)\n
y(0)     []\n
y(1)     []\n
y(2)     <<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>\n
y(3)     Catch 0x00007fe26819a9b8 (emqx_cm_locker:trans/3 + 424)\n\n
0x00007fde7c33faf0 Return addr 0x00007fe268197608 (emqx_connection:with_channel/3 + 232)\n
y(0)     []\n
y(1)     []\n
y(2)     {channel,#{clean_start=>false,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,conn_mod=>emqx_connection,conn_props=>#{},connected_at=>1701153199092,disconnected_at=>1701153199091,expiry_interval=>71680,keepalive=>60,peercert=>nossl,peername=>{{192,168,30,43},57440},proto_name=><<\"MQTT\">>,proto_ver=>4,receive_maximum=>32,sockname=>{{192,168,30,16},1883},socktype=>tcp,username=><<\"admin\">>},#{anonymous=>true,auth_result=>success,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,is_bridge=>false,is_superuser=>false,mountpoint=>undefined,peerhost=>{192,168,30,43},protocol=>mqtt,sockport=>1883,username=><<\"admin\">>,zone=>external},{session,#{<<\"product/direct/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/direct/info/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/direct/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gateway/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gateway/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw/info/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw_chlidev/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw_chlidev/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/order_return/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}}},0,false,{inflight,32,{0,nil}},{mqueue,true,1916800,0,0,none,infinity,{queue,[],[],0}},1,30000,#{},19168,300000,1701152524859},{keepalive,45000,0,0},undefined,#{inbound=>#{},outbound=>#{}},undefined,#{},undefined,#{alive_timer=>#Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.15885>,expire_timer=>#Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.17052>},connected,false,false,[]}\ny(3)     #{}\n\n0x00007fde7c33fb18 Return addr 0x00007fe2681948b0 (emqx_connection:process_msg/3 + 136)\n
y(0)     []\n
y(1)     {state,esockd_transport,#Port<0.17354>,{{192,168,30,43},57440},{{192,168,30,16},1883},closed,19168,undefined,undefined,{none,#{max_size=>19248576,strict_mode=>false,version=>4}},#Fun<emqx_frame.4.19219284926>,{channel,#{clean_start=>false,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,conn_mod=>emqx_connection,conn_props=>#{},connected_at=>1701153199074,disconnected_at=>1701153199091,expiry_interval=>71680,keepalive=>60,peercert=>nossl,peername=>{{192,168,30,43},57440},proto_name=><<\"MQTT\">>,proto_ver=>4,receive_maximum=>32,sockname=>{{192,168,30,16},1883},socktype=>tcp,username=><<\"admin\">>},#{anonymous=>true,auth_result=>success,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,is_bridge=>false,is_superuser=>false,mountpoint=>undefined,peerhost=>{192,168,30,43},protocol=>mqtt,sockport=>1883,username=><<\"admin\">>,zone=>external},{session,#{<<\"product/direct/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/direct/info/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/direct/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gateway/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gateway/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw/info/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw_chlidev/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw_chlidev/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/order_return/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}}},0,false,{inflight,32,{0,nil}},{mqueue,true,1916800,0,0,none,infinity,{queue,[],[],0}},1,30000,#{},19168,300000,1701152524859},{keepalive,45000,0,0},undefined,#{inbound=>#{},outbound=>#{}},undefined,#{},undefined,#{alive_timer=>#Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.15885>,expire_timer=>#Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.17052>},disconnected,false,false,[]},{gc_state,#{cnt=>{16000,16000},oct=>{16777216,16777216}}},#Ref<0.2499957634.4089708546.12231>,15000,undefined}\n
y(2)     []\n\n0x00007fde7c33fb38 Return addr 0x00007fe26a4ddee8 (proc_lib:wake_up/3 + 1168)\n
y(0)     []\n
y(1)     {state,esockd_transport,#Port<0.17354>,{{192,168,30,43},57440},{{192,168,30,16},1883},closed,19168,undefined,undefined,{none,#{max_size=>19248576,strict_mode=>false,version=>4}},#Fun<emqx_frame.4.19219284926>,{channel,#{clean_start=>false,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,conn_mod=>emqx_connection,conn_props=>#{},connected_at=>1701153199074,disconnected_at=>1701153199091,expiry_interval=>71680,keepalive=>60,peercert=>nossl,peername=>{{192,168,30,43},57440},proto_name=><<\"MQTT\">>,proto_ver=>4,receive_maximum=>32,sockname=>{{192,168,30,16},1883},socktype=>tcp,username=><<\"admin\">>},#{anonymous=>true,auth_result=>success,clientid=><<\"192.168.30.16_1701152524553\">>,is_bridge=>false,is_superuser=>false,mountpoint=>undefined,peerhost=>{192,168,30,43},protocol=>mqtt,sockport=>1883,username=><<\"admin\">>,zone=>external},{session,#{<<\"product/direct/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/direct/info/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/direct/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gateway/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gateway/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw/info/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw_chlidev/data/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/gw_chlidev/status/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}},<<\"product/order_return/#\">>=>#{nl=>0,qos=>2,rap=>0,rh=>0,sub_props=>#{}}},0,false,{inflight,32,{0,nil}},{mqueue,true,1916800,0,0,none,infinity,{queue,[],[],0}},1,30000,#{},19168,300000,1701152524859},{keepalive,45000,0,0},undefined,#{inbound=>#{},outbound=>#{}},undefined,#{},undefined,#{alive_timer=>#Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.15885>,expire_timer=>#Ref<0.2499957634.4089446403.17052>},disconnected,false,false,[]},{gc_state,#{cnt=>{16000,16000},oct=>{16777216,16777216}}},#Ref<0.2499957634.4089708546.12231>,15000,undefined}\n
y(2)     <0.1652.0>\n
y(3)     Catch 0x00007fe2681948b0 (emqx_connection:process_msg/3 + 136)\n\n0x00007fde7c33fb60 Return addr 0x000055a7bdfc8248 (<terminate process normally>)\n
y(0)     []\n
y(1)     []\n
y(2)     Catch 0x00007fe26a4ddf08 (proc_lib:wake_up/3 + 152)\n">>}
```

Comment: anyone who knows?